# On the definition of free algebra and localization of a non-commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, algebras

Below is a  [construction (p15)](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/3866) of the localization of a non-commutative ring $A$ by a subset $S$.

> **Construction 3.1** Form the free algebra on a set which is in bijection with $S$ $$A\langle i_s \colon s \in S\rangle$$ and impose the relation that $i_s$ is a two-sided inverse of $s \in S$ for each $s \in S$: $$S^{-1}A := \frac{A\langle i_s \colon s \in S\rangle}{\langle si_s-1, i_s s-1 \colon s \in S \rangle}\,.$$ Then define $\phi A \to S^{-1}A$ by letting $\phi(a)$ be the image of $a$ in $S^{-1}A$. By definition $\phi(S)$ consists of the units of $S^{-1}A$.

What I am confused about is what is precisely meant here by

> Form the free algebra on a set which is in bijection with $S$, $A \langle i_s \colon s \in S \rangle$.

What is the definition of free algebra over a non-commutative ring $A$?

Comment: That's correct: a free algebra is usually constructed using a commutative ring. You can probably still freely generate a ring using $A$ and $S$, but one should really be more careful before calling it an *algebra*.

Comment: *And I do not understand how we can apply the definition of free algebra here.* You mean, you don't understand how to apply it considering the definition at the link requires $A$ to be commutative? You're right, that definition would be inapplicable in this context.

Comment: So I am confused at what precisely is the object $A\langle i_s \rangle$?

Comment: Doesn't the wiki explain that completely? it consists of finite products of elements of $S$ made into linear combinations with coefficients from $A$.

Comment: If this is the case how do we even make sense of the quotient with elements of form $i_s s -1$ . Assuming $A \langle i_s \rangle =\sum \sum a \prod i  $ ( the last expression is in form given wiki). MO states that $A \langle i_s \rangle$ is the ring generated by formal combinations $r_1s_1^{-1} \cdots$ ( and we quotient out by inverse relation) (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97556/noncommutative-localization-of-a-ring-complete-construction)

Comment: If it were a free *algebra*, then $A$ would commute with the adjoined elements, and then $i_ss-1=si_s-1$ is a linear combination exactly as described. If it's a ring freely generated with $A$ and $S$, then the expression of elements will be much more complicated in general.

Comment: Sorry, how does this follow? I am still confused - what is the definition of free algebra over $R$ non commutative?

Comment: I don't know a definition when $A$ is noncommutative either. I am applying the defintion at the wiki you linked.  Where is this source where they tried to use $A$ noncommutative?

Comment: I have linked the source, it is a set of notes on non commutative rings.

Comment: It is simpler to describe that ring as the free product of A and the free Z-algebra on the variables.

Answer (score 3):

There's no *standard* definition of a free $A$-algebra when $A$ is non-commutative, but my guess is that it can only really mean one thing in this context: the smallest ring that contains $A$ and all of the $i_s$, with no extra relations imposed upon them (in particular, $i_s a \neq a i_s$ for $s\in S, a\in A$). Elements of $A$ multiply with each other in the usual way, and that's all.

This ring is obviously horrendously large. Even after you quotient out by the relation $``i_s = s^{-1}"$, elements of the resulting ring $S^{-1}A$ might *still* look like $a_1 (s_1 s_2 s_3)^{-1} a_2 (s_4 s_5)^{-1} a_3 \dots a_m s_n^{-1}$, with no further simplification possible. This is a horrible outcome if what we were hoping for (like the commutative case) was a ring consisting of simple fractions like $``a/s"$.

Luckily (see Definition 3.4 and the remark after it), in many 'nice' cases you *can* in fact simplify everything to a simple left fraction $s^{-1} a$, or a simple right fraction $a's'^{-1}$, or either.

Comment: So is it right to say that elements of this ring are finite sums of finite products of elements: $a \in A$ and $i_{s_1} \cdots i_{s_k}$ where $s_i \in S$.

Comment: That's how I understand it.

Comment: Indeed. This ring is mostly useless: it's only purpose is to show that the localization always exists, but it is essentially useless, as you cannot compute anything with it.

Comment: Moreover, this localization can well be trivial. An extreme case occurs when one of the elements you want to invert is a zero divisor, of course. But there are other situations in which this collapses.