# Constructing an integral domain with a specific subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

What tools are available for constructing various (noncommutative) domains with a given subdomain? That is, how can I begin to examine various domains which contain the domain $S$, other than obviously $S$ itself?

If we needed only a ring $R$ with a subring $S$, we could take direct sums of $S$ with other rings, but unfortunately the direct sum does not preserve the domain property, so this construction method is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the more familiar commutative case, you could look at certain quotients of polynomial rings over $S$. The quotient $S[x]/I$ will contain a copy of $S$ so long as $I$ trivially intersects the zeroth graded component of $S[x].$ Furthermore, if $S$ is commutative and unital, $S[x]/I$ will be a domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal. This will give you many examples of *commutative* domains that have $S$ as a subring.

This recipe only has to be fudged a little bit to allow for noncommutative quotient rings. Instead of starting with a polynomial ring over $S$, start with a [free algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) over $S$ like $S\langle x,y\rangle$ instead. Then the quotient $S\langle x, y \rangle/I$ will be a domain if and only if $I$ is a [completely prime ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings).

Comment: How can one take the free algebra over $S$ if $S$ is not commutative?

Comment: @MightyTyGuy With great difficulty. If $S$ is not commutative then the usual "free algebra" construction only gets you the structure of an $S$-module. For multiplication in the free algebra, or generally multiplication in any $S$-algebra $A$, for $s \in S$ and $a,b \in A$ you need to have $s\cdot(ab) = (s\cdot a)b = a(s\cdot b)$. You see $s$ has to "*commute with*" $a$. You can read the comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2649257/167197) to learn more.